# Plotting bar chart with condition on 3rd variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset in this form :
Year, Temperature, Distance from the sea. Distance from the sea is a categorical variable Far or near. The others are discrete and continuous data respectively. I need to come up with a line chart plotting Year and temperature for both the levels of the variable Distance from sea i.e. I need to have a line chart showing the relationship between year and Temperature for both places Near and far on the same plot. Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a barchart with data from jazzurro:

```
ggplot(foo)+geom_bar(aes(year, temperature, fill=distance), stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With ggolot2, you may want something like this then.

```
library(ggplot2)
year <- rep(c(2001:2010), each = 1, times = 2)
temperature <- runif(20, 0, 35)
distance <- rep(c("far","near"), each = 10, times = 1)

foo <- data.frame(year, distance, temperature)
foo$year <- as.factor(foo$year)
foo$temperature <- as.numeric(foo$temperature)


ggplot(foo, aes(x = year, y = temperature, color = distance, group = distance)) +
    geom_line(stat="identity")
```

Comment: This is a line chart and not a bar chart (see title).

Comment: True, but he said line chart in his question.

Answer (score 0):

And a few base R solutions, using the same setup:

```
year <- rep(c(2001:2010), each = 1, times = 2)
temperature <- runif(20, 0, 35)
distance <- rep(c("far","near"), each = 10, times = 1)

foo <- data.frame(year, distance, temperature)
foo$year <- as.factor(foo$year)
foo$temperature <- as.numeric(foo$temperature)
```

You can then do

```
plot(year, temperature, data = foo[foo$distance == "near", ], type = "l")
lines(year, temperature, data = foo[foo$distance == "far", ])
```

or if the data isn't sorted, you can do something like

```
foo_sorted <- foo[order(foo$year), ]
plot(year, temperature, data = foo_sorted[foo_sorted$distance == "near", ], type = "l")
lines(year, temperature, data = foo_sorted[foo_sorted$distance == "far", ])
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
ts.plot(cbind(foo$temperature[foo$distance == "near"], foo$temperature[foo$distance == "far])
```

or the same thing in matrix notation

```
ts.plot(cbind(foo[foo$distance == "near", "temperature"], foo$temperature[foo$distance == "far])
```

You also might want to `reshape` your data.

```
library(reshape2)
foo_wide <- cast(melt(foo), year ~ distance + variable)
ts.plot(foo_wide[, 2:3])
```

And finally, the `zoo` package has its own set of very nice plotting methods for time series objects.